# How to trace the history of all the domains used an IP that I know?

Tags: asp.net, security, dns

I have an IP. Now I want to see all the domains used this ip. Where and how can I see that?

Answer (score 0):

You can search on bing.com

```
IP:193.2.2.2
```

Will return you all the domains indexed by bing and hosted by that ip.

Comment: what if i'm checking this from organization lan?

Comment: Also this hack will generate too many results for same domains. I just want some list of history without going lost of many search results

Comment: This is the best free method that I know.

Comment: You can try archive.org ... don't know if they have this service, but is possible to find something there.

Comment: No, this is will not help, Thanks for trying to help